# Making A Close Image Appear On Top Right Corner Of A DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml

I wanted to know how to make a small cross (close) image appear on the top right inside of a div.  Using CSS and XHTML.  Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't a "code it for me site." As much as we like to help, it's better if you can give us a tried example that failed :)

Comment: lol, I know, but but I haven't got the faintest idea.

Comment: Haha! Well there is an example now :)

Comment: I was like putting the image inside a div and floating it right, had  the basic idea... :p

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do it this way: [jsfiddle.net/7JEAZ/1317](http://jsfiddle.net/7JEAZ/1317/)

Code snippet:

```css
#panel{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}
#close{
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:30px;
    height:29px;
    background:url(https://web.archive.org/web/20110126035650/http://digitalsbykobke.com/images/close.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel"><a id="close" href="#"></a></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

In-case its any help, here is another example with the close button over the top right corner of the DIV, the code is an example showing it with two different sized div's and the jQuery to close the parent div of the image clicked. There is also a link to reshow the div.

**CSS:**

```
#content{
    border: solid black;   
    width: 70%;
}

#info{
    border: solid red;   
    width: 50%;
}

.close-image{
    display: block;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    top:-10px;
    right: -10px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="toggle-content">Show / Hide content</a>
<br/><br/>
<div id="content">
    <img class="close-image" src="http://residentialsearch.savills.co.uk/Content/Images/icon_close.png" />
    <b><u>Content:</u></b><br/>
    This is the info inside the div!
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div id="info">
    <img class="close-image" src="http://residentialsearch.savills.co.uk/Content/Images/icon_close.png" />
    <b><u>Info:</u></b><br/>
    Click the close button to hide this info!
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".close-image").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});

$("#toggle-content").click(function() {
    $("#content").slideToggle();
});
```

An example: **[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/yzwh5/3/)**

Answer (score 3):

this simple example may help. =]

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://96pix.com/images/renee-v.jpg" />
    <a href="#" id="close"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thumbnail {
    position: relative;
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
}

.thumbnail img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#close {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    top: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    background: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/kyo-tux/delikate/512/Close-icon.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/PPN7Q/26/