# Putting close button on the right side of the parent div

Tags: css

I am trying to have a close button on the right side of the div but a little bit higher than the div. Something like on the following picture:

[image]

After searching for a little bit I found the following relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088643/making-a-close-image-appear-on-top-right-corner-of-a-div), I tried to modify it a little bit to get what I want.

My attempt can be [viewed on the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/Lf7B2/1/):

```
<div class="area">
    <span class="close">X</span>
    <div class="areaInside">some data</div>
</div>
.areaInside{
    border: 2px dashed #bbb;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #bbb;
    min-height: 80px;
}
.area{
    width:70%;
    height:100px;
}
.close{
    float:right;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

But clearly it does not do what I wanted. I want the close button to be above the area and a little bit to the left. How can I achieve this without changing the markup (only with css).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf7B2/4/)

```
position:relative;
margin-top:-15px;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **`line-height`** in this case.

```
.close{
    float:right;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 2px;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/Lf7B2/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `positions`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf7B2/5/)**

```
.area{
    width:70%;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}
.close{
   position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    top: -10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.close {
float: right;
cursor: pointer;
font-weight: bold;
position: relative;
margin-top: -15px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf7B2/12/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
.close {
float: right;
cursor: pointer;
font-weight: bold;
display: block;
margin-top: -17px;
margin-right: 8px;
background: red;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf7B2/10/)

Answer (score 1):

**[See updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf7B2/13/)**

**Use Position concept make parent property relative and child property absolute
now child css work relative to parent**

```
.areaInside{
    border: 2px dashed #bbb;
    -moz-border-radius: 10x;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10x;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #bbb;
    min-height: 80px;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.area{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}
.close{
    float:right;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
   right: 2px;
   top: -14px;
}
```